# Ubuntu Server - Como puedo hacer para que solo me muestre los siguientes requerimientos

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-server

"Se presenten solamente las columnas de PID, USER, VIRT, RES y COMMAND, además debe ordenarlo por la columna de COMMAND"

Sé que comando "TOP" muestra lo necesario pero necesito que solo me muestre "PID, USER, VIRT, RES y COMMAND" ademas de ordenarlo.

Comment: Hola @Warren! Como va? Te recomiendo que te des una vueltesita por el [reccorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) asi ves como formular una pregunta y de paso obtienes tu primera medalla.Googleando un poco me encontre con esto ```top -bn 1 | grep "^ " | awk '{ printf("%-8s  %-8s  %-8s\n", $9, $10, $12); }' | head -n 5``` aqui te dejo el [enlace](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86594/431049)

Answer (score 0):

El programa `htop` te va ayudar en eso.

- Para seleccionar las columnas: una vez abierto -> <kbd>F2</kbd> SETUP -> Setup - menú Columns
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- Quita y pon los conceptos necesarios, con la ayuda de <kbd>F9</kbd>.<kbd>F10</kbd> cuando termines ( abajo tienes los atajos de teclado)
- Resultado final

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes ordenar los campos pinxando directamente a la columna Command con el ratón, o bien con al tecla <kbd>F6</kbd>-SortBy